# Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'The sku 'ElasticPool' specified is invalid.'

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I'm trying to clone an Azure SQL Database using the PSCmdlet `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy` (after being told that `Restore-AzSqlDatabase` won't let me do cross-server copies).  My command is as follows:

```
New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy   -ServerName $SourceDatabase.ServerName `
                        -ResourceGroupName $SourceDatabase.ResourceGroupName `
                        -DatabaseName $SourceDatabase.DatabaseName `
                        -ServiceObjectiveName $SourceDatabase.CurrentServiceObjectiveName `
                        -CopyServerName $TargetServerName `
                        -CopyResourceGroupName $TargetResourceGroupName `
                        -CopyDatabaseName $TargetDBName `
                        -ElasticPoolName $ElasticPoolName`
                        -ErrorAction stop
```

The source database is in a different server and resource group than the target, and in a different elastic pool than the target will be.

I've checked and double-checked all of my parameters to make sure they are correct, and I ran it with -whatif and everything looks good (except the creation date is 1/1/0001 but i'm not super concerned about that yet)

However, when I run the command, I get `New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'. Additional Info:'The sku 'ElasticPool' specified is invalid.'`  Any input would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you want to copy a database to different sql server, different elastic pool?

Comment: As per the error, it might be because the elastic pool name you have specified in the argument is invalid. Still more details on what you trying to achieve is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new Elastic Pool has the same name and as the old Elastic Pool. Also make sure the sku are same for both the elastic pools. If the resource groups are in different regions, the sku for elastic pools may differ causing issues while copying the database.

SQL server - sql_server_A
--- Elastic Pool - elastic_pool_1
----- database - template_db

SQL server - sql_server_B
--- Elastic Pool - elastic_pool_1 (name equal to Elastic Pool from sql_server_A)

References:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/issues/41

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-move-database-between-pools-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/createorupdate

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/elasticpools/createorupdate

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "-ServiceObjectiveName" parameter. Only -elasticpool OR -ServiceObjectiveName can be used.